# check even number in mutidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, numbers

Hi i have a problem when code, I want to check an even number in multidimensional array and then change to 'X' if there are even numbers in row or column more than equals to 3 times appear but I change it all to 'X' eventhough it's less than 3. my code like this :

```
function evenNumbers(numbers){

  for(var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
     for(var j = 0; j < numbers[i].length; j++){
        if(numbers[i][j] % 2 == 0){
           numbers[i][j] = 'X'
        }
     }
  }
  return numbers
}


console.log(evenNumbers([
  [1, 2, 4, 6, 5],
  [6, 17, 8, 11, 10],
  [8, 11, 10, 18, 16],
  [18, 12, 19, 27, 21],
  [22, 10, 12, 22, 12]
]));
```

expected output :

```
 [1, 'X', 'X', 'X', 5],
 ['X', 17, 'X', 11, 10],
 ['X', 11, 'X', 'X', 'X'],
 ['X', 12, 19,  27 , 21],
 [''X, 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X']
```

what I got :

```
[ [ 1, 'X', 'X', 'X', 5 ],
  [ 'X', 17, 'X', 11, 'X' ],
  [ 'X', 11, 'X', 'X', 'X' ],
  [ 'X', 'X', 19, 27, 21 ],
  [ 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X' ] ]
```

Thanks, in advance
Help me with no ES6 built-in just regular JS, please. Thanks again

Comment: It's not entirely clear why you think `12` and `10` should not be converted to `X`, could you add some detail to the question to illustrate that?

Answer (score 0):

You could use some to make the check, then map

```js
const arr = [
  [1, 2, 4, 6, 5],
  [6, 17, 8, 11, 10],
  [8, 11, 10, 18, 16],
  [18, 12, 19, 27, 21],
  [22, 10, 12, 22, 12]
];

function xEvens(arr) {
  return arr.map(row => {
    let i = 0;
    let shouldChange = row.some(n => n % 2 === 0 && ++i >= 3);
    return shouldChange ? row.map(n => n % 2 === 0 ? 'X' : n) : row;
  });
}

console.log(xEvens(arr));
```

Pre es6 version

```js
var arr = [
  [1, 2, 4, 6, 5],
  [6, 17, 8, 11, 10],
  [8, 11, 10, 18, 16],
  [18, 12, 19, 27, 21],
  [22, 10, 12, 22, 12]
];

function xEvens(arr) {
  return arr.map(function(row) {
    var i = 0;
    var shouldChange = row.some(function(n) {
      return n % 2 === 0 && ++i >= 3;
    });
    return shouldChange ? row.map(function(n) {
      return n % 2 === 0 ? 'X' : n
    }) : row;
  });
}

console.log(xEvens(arr));
```

Comment: fyi, the question asked for no es6

Answer (score 0):

You can try following approach:

#### Idea:

- Loop on array and return an array where `X` is replaced for even numbers.
- Keep a track of count of replacements.
- If count matches the threshold, return this new array.
- If not, return the original array.

This way you will not need an extra loop just to check the validity for replacement.

```js
function replaceEvensWithCondition(arr, minCount, replaceChar) {
  return arr.map(function(row) {
    var count = 0;
    var updatedArray = row.map(function(n) {
      var isEven = n % 2 === 0;
      count += +isEven;
      return isEven ? replaceChar : n;
    });
    return count >= minCount ? updatedArray : row
  });
}

var arr = [ [1, 2, 4, 6, 5], [6, 17, 8, 11, 10], [8, 11, 10, 18, 16], [18, 12, 19, 27, 21], [22, 10, 12, 22, 12] ];

console.log(replaceEvensWithCondition(arr, 3, 'X'));
```

Comment: Thanks, is there any way I don't use map, filter, reduce etc ?

Comment: @AndyWarhol you can do it with for as well. Any specific reason to avoid map though? Note, map is a part of ES5 and will not give browser compatibility issue, unless you can to support IE8 or before, for which I'm not sure

Comment: As a beginner in code, I need to understand how this thing works. Me, myself just entered code world as a student. We need to know manually before using any method. Thank you

Comment: @AndyWarhol Please refer [MDN - Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and try to back track the approach. This way, if you fail, create a fiddle and I'll answer your queries with example and in this process, you'll learn few things!